# Saving grayscale image to a directory in python

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, image-processing

I have a piece of code that takes in image data as grayscale values, and then converts into an image using matplotlib below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy

image_data = image_result.GetNDArray()
numpy.savetxt('data.cvs', image_data)

# Draws an image on the current figure
image = plt.imshow(image_data, cmap='gray')
```

I want to be able to export this data to LabView as a .png file. So I need to save these image to a folder where LabView and display them. Is there a function with pillow or os that can do this?

Comment: Hi there! Because i don`t know the answer to your question if you are using np&matplt i recommend using OpenCV. There you can very easily open a img, convert it to grayscale and then save it whereever you want to.

Comment: welcome. since you appear new to the site, perhaps take the [tour]. you can vote on answers (or soon you will). if an answer solved your problem, you can mark it as "the solution".

Answer (score 0):

`plt.imsave('output.png', image)`

Does this work?

Answer (score 0):

If `image_data` is a Numpy array of shape `height x width` with `dtype=np.uint8` or `dtype=np.uint16`, you can make a **PIL Image** and save it as a PNG like this:

```
from PIL import Image

# Make PIL Image from Numpy array
pImage = Image.fromarray(image_data)
pImage.save('forLabView.png')
```

---

You can equally use **OpenCV** to save a Numpy array as a PNG for **LabView** like this:

```
import cv2

# Save Numpy array as PNG
cv2.imwrite('forLabView.png', image_data)
```

---

Check what your array is with:

```
print(image_data.shape, image_data.dtype)
```